# Should default POJO parameter resolution add the parameter to the model?

Tags: spring-mvc

I just spent some time troubleshooting an aspect of Spring MVC's default handler method parameter resolution and I'd like to ask those closer to the project if this behavior is intended or if it'd be reasonable to open a ticket suggesting a change.

The issue has to do with the default resolution of POJO-style objects in method parameters like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/endpointwithparams")
public String endpointWithParams(EndpointParams params) {
  // Do some stuff
  return "viewname";
}
```

With no annotations or custom argument resolvers, Spring will attempt to bind the EndpointParams object by matching request parameters to its field names. It will even run validators if any are configured. This seems great - it lets me write simple POJO objects to organize related sets of parameters without having to have a custom argument resolver for each one.

The part that throws me off is that after the EndpointParams object is created it will *also* be automatically added to the model. This is because the actual resolver of this parameter will be a ModelAttributeMethodProcessor with its "annotationNotRequired" flag set to true. I don't want this parameter added to the model - its presence causes some trouble down the line - and it certainly wasn't intuitive to me that I should expect that addition to happen for a parameter that wasn't annotated with @ModelAttribute.

This behavior is also inconsistent with what happens when you have a "simple" request parameter like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/endpointwithparams")
public String endpointWithParams(String param) {
  // Do some stuff
  return "viewname";
}
```

In the above example, the String param will be resolved by the RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver, which will *not* add anything to the model.

Would it be reasonable to suggest that better default logic for non-annotated POJO parameters would be the same binding and validation that currently occurs, but without the automatic addition to the model? Or is there some context I'm missing that makes the full @ModelAttribute behavior the best default choice?